# How to convert charset of a file

Tags: linux, php

I have a file (php file) which is has a charset that I need to convert to us-ascii. How can  Ido this on Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `iconv`.

```
iconv -f cp1251 -t ascii//translit < from.txt > to.txt
```